# How to aggregate DataFrame to stay rows with the highest date and add new column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below ("date_col" is in "datetime64" format):

```
ID  | date_col   | purchase
----|------------|-------
111 | 2019-01-05 | apple
111 | 2019-05-22 | onion
222 | 2020-11-04 | banana
333 | 2020-04-19 | orange
```

I need to aggregate above table in the following way:

1. add column "col1" with number of purchases which was made by client ("ID")
2. If some client ("ID") is duplicated - stay only one row with the highest date

So as a result I need something like below:

```
ID  | date_col   | purchase | col1
----|------------|----------|-----
111 | 2019-05-22 | onion    | 2
222 | 2020-11-04 | banana   | 1
333 | 2020-04-19 | orange   | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dataframe is sorted on `date_col` column, you can use `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
g.last().merge(g.size())
```

---

```
    ID    date_col purchase  size
0  111  2019-05-22    onion     2
1  222  2020-11-04   banana     1
2  333  2020-04-19   orange     1
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way:

```
df['col1'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
df = df.sort_values('date_col').groupby('ID').tail(1)
```

output:

```
>>
    ID    date_col purchase  col1
1  111  2019-05-22    onion     2
3  333  2020-04-19   orange     1
2  222  2020-11-04   banana     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try create a new `count` column using `groupby.transform` and get the max date by selecting with `groupby.idmax`

```py
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])
df = (df.assign(col1=df.groupby('ID')['purchase'].transform('count'))
      .loc[lambda df: df.groupby('ID')['date_col'].idxmax()])
```

```
print(df)

    ID   date_col purchase  col1
1  111 2019-05-22    onion     2
2  222 2020-11-04   banana     1
3  333 2020-04-19   orange     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col1'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
df.sort_values('date_col').drop_duplicates('ID',keep='last')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.